# How to show fallback text for characters not supported by the browser?

Tags: javascript, css, html, unicode

### How to have the browser show fallback text instead of square boxes for text the browser doesn't support?

This happens for example if no font is present to match the expected characters (e.g: Japanese text without any Japanese font installed).

---

For example, if "日本語" (Japanese) cannot be displayed, I'd like the browser to show "Japanese" instead of "[][][]".

Other example, for text in French, say "Fran**ç**ais", if the character "ç" cannot be shown, I'd like the rendered text to be "Fran**c**ais" instead of "Fran[]ais".

**Constraints:**

- HTML5/CSS
- no additional library (no middleware, no framework),
- <del>no JavaScript, unless it is the only way to achieve the goal?</del>
- Javascript is allowed
  (**edit**)
- simple and elegant solutions preferred

---

**Any idea?**

In case you have a solution, can you please show it using the following sample code?

**Sample code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test page</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Test page</h1>

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a href="index.html"><b>English</b>
  <br/>[no need for fallback text in case of English.]</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a href="index_fr.html"><b>Français</b>
  <br/>[how to show fallback text if 'ç' cannot be displayed properly?]</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a href="index_ja.html"><b>日本語</b>
  <br/>[how to show fallback text here if '日本語' cannot be displayed properly?]</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not sure this is possible without JS. What about detecting the user's locale server side and based on that make a high likelihood assumption and display accordingly? I.e. if user's locale is Japanese, display non-latin characters, if not use latin.

Comment: All right, so answers using Javascript are welcome ! (I edited the question).